# python reshaping a dataframe

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have a bunck of rows in my datafram2 that looks like this. lots of rows with 2 columns.

```
player         pos

Blake Bortles   QB
Alvin Kamara    RB
Dion Lewis      RB
Keenan Allen    WR
Michael Thomas  WR
Tyrell Williams WR
Hunter Henry    TE
Stephen Gostkowski  K
Los Angeles Chargers    D
Totals       Team 1.0
Blake Bortles   QB
Alvin Kamara    RB
Dion Lewis  RB
Keenan Allen    WR
Michael Thomas  WR
Tyrell Williams WR
Hunter Henry    TE
Stephen Gostkowski  K
Jacksonville Jaguars    D
Totals  Team 2.0
Blake Bortles   QB
Todd Gurley RB
Alvin Kamara    RB
Michael Thomas  WR
Cooper Kupp WR
Tyrell Williams WR
Hunter Henry    TE
Stephen Gostkowski  K
Los Angeles Chargers    D
```

I'm trying to reshape it so every 11th row starts a new row, and the pos value is the column name. So I'd like it to look like this:

```
 QB                 RB               RB                 WR               WR                     WR                   TE                      K                D                team
 Blake Bortles      Alvin Kamara     Dion Lewis     Keenan Allen      Michael Thomas     Tyrell Williams     Hunter Henry      Stephen Gostkowski     Los Angeles Chargers
```

The last column of Totals Team 1.0 doesnt really matter. But then I'd like row 2 to be the next set of players. I've tried reshape.

I've managed to do it if I drop the `pos` column an do:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(rearrange.values.reshape(-1, 10), 
                columns=['QB','RB','RB','WR','WR','WR','TE','K','D','Team'])
```

But how can I do it with the `pos` column there?

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need if order and values of `pos` is same in each group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['player'].values.reshape(-1, 10), 
                columns=df['pos'].iloc[:9].tolist() + ['total'])
print (df)
              QB            RB            RB              WR              WR  \
0  Blake Bortles  Alvin Kamara    Dion Lewis    Keenan Allen  Michael Thomas   
1  Blake Bortles  Alvin Kamara    Dion Lewis    Keenan Allen  Michael Thomas   
2  Blake Bortles   Todd Gurley  Alvin Kamara  Michael Thomas     Cooper Kupp   

                WR            TE                   K                     D  \
0  Tyrell Williams  Hunter Henry  Stephen Gostkowski  Los Angeles Chargers   
1  Tyrell Williams  Hunter Henry  Stephen Gostkowski  Jacksonville Jaguars   
2  Tyrell Williams  Hunter Henry  Stephen Gostkowski  Los Angeles Chargers   

         total  
0  Totals Team  
1  Totals Team  
2  Totals Team
```